# Round time string in gap of 30 minutes

Tags: php

I have a time string in UNIX format . I need to round that string to closest interval of 30 minutes.

For eg: I have time as 9:20 AM than it should round it to 9:30 AM.

If minutes are greater than 30 like 9:45 AM it should round to 10:00 AM.

I have tried this so far:

```
$hour = date('H', $ltdaytmfstr);
$minute = (date('i', $ltdaytmfstr)>30)?'00':'30';
echo "$hour:$minute";
```

`$ltdaytmfstr` is time string in unix format.

Any suggestions? It would be better if I can get the value returned in UNIX format .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try this: This will round it to the nearest half an hour.

Use `ceil` function.

```
<?php

 $rounded = date('H:i:s', ceil(strtotime('16:20:34')/1800)*1800);
 echo $rounded;


?>

Output: 16:30:00
```

http://codepad.org/4WwNO5Rt

Comment: This won't match the requirement that "*If minutes are greater than 30 like 9:45 AM it should round to 10:00 AM.*". At `16:41` it would still be `16:30`.

Comment: @Qirel  now it will meet the requirement.. i changed it to ceil.. thanks for notifying me.

Answer (score 2):

If you use DateTime:

```
$dt = new \DateTime;
$diff = $dt
          ->add( 
               //This just calculates number of seconds from the next 30 minute interval
               new \DateInterval("PT".((30 - $dt->format("i"))*60-$dt->format("s"))."S")
          );

 echo $dt->getTimestamp();
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is what you are looking for

```
function round_timestamp($timestamp){
  $hour = date("H", strtotime($timestamp));
  $minute = date("i", strtotime($timestamp));

  if ($minute<15) {
    return date('H:i', strtotime("$hour:00") );
  } elseif($minute>=15 and $minute<45){
    return date('H:i', strtotime("$hour:30") );
  } elseif($minute>=45) {
    $hour = $hour + 1;
    return date('H:i', strtotime("$hour:00") );
  }
}

echo round_timestamp("11:59");
// 00:00
echo round_timestamp("10:59");
// 11:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Since UNIX time is in seconds, you can just transform it to 30 minute units, round, and convert back to seconds.

```
$timestamp = time();
$rounded = round($timestamp / (30 * 60)) * 30 * 60
```

You can also use `floor()` or `ceil()` to round up or down if needed.